# Writing js script inside popup window

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add js script into a popup I opened but having trouble doing so.

Here is my code:

```
function openGame() {
    gameWindow = window.open("", "gameWindow", "top=500, left=500, height=988, width=1263");
    gameWindow.document.write('<html><head>')
    gameWindow.document.write('<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"cssbutton.css\">')
    gameWindow.document.write('<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"sbg_style.css\">')
}
// at this point I would like to add the following script
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checker0").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px', top:'250px'});
    });
});
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a template for you:

```
var gameWindow = window.open("", 
    "gameWindow", 
    "top=500, left=500, height=988, width=1263");    // external/pop-up window
gameWindow.document.write('<div id="checker">+++++++++</div>');   // example html element
// adding a listener to the element on a external/pop-up window
// there is extended notation for jQuery selector
$("#checker", gameWindow.document).click(function(e){ // listener of element on a external window
  // example of manipulation on a "#checker" div
  $(e.target).text("---------"); // there you can do anything with elements on external window
});
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/qotaxoguvi/1/

Comment: it doesn't work! I use Google Chrome and when I inspect the page in the header part I can't see the listener element code.

Comment: I added the demo. You probably forgot to wrap all that code in `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

Comment: Your example works great!!

tell me, I'm trying to animate the div and it doesn't work.
Instead of: $(e.target).text("--------");
I do: $('div').animate({left: '50px'}); any idea why?

Comment: ok, got it! all I had to do is use e.target instead of 'div'.

Comment: @Shvalb: Yes! Now, you can do anything from parent window code (controller). Even create new nodes and listeners for them.

Comment: you are so kind so I find myself asking you more and more questions :-)

My question: I would like to know if it's possible to add listeners to buttons or div dynamically, meaning after the page was already loaded?? I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: You should write new question with your piece of code and you will get the answer. It is the main idea of the stackowerflow service. I will be happy to help you.

Comment: Big help: the 2-argument `$(selector, popup_window.document)`